# 2-steps query in OrientDB

Tags: orientdb

I'm evaluating OrientDB and Neo4j in this simple toy example composed by:

- Employees, identified by `eid`
- Meetings, identified by `mid` and having `start` and `end` attributes encoding their start and end DateTime.

Both entities are represented by different classes of vertices, namely `Employee` and `CalendarEvent`, which are connected by `Involves` edges specifying that `CalendarEvent-[Involves]->Employee`.

My task is to write a query that returns, for each pair of employees, the date/time of their first meeting and the number of meetings they co-attended.
In Cypher I would write something like:

```
MATCH (e0: Employee)<-[:INVOLVES]-(c:CalendarEvent)-[:INVOLVES]->(e1: Employee)
WHERE e0.eid > e1.eid
RETURN e0.eid, e1.eid, min(c.start) as first_met, count(*) as frequency
```

I wrote the following query for OrientDB:

```
SELECT eid, other, count(*) AS frequency, min(start) as first_met
FROM (
  SELECT eid, event.start as start, event.out('Involves').eid as other
  FROM (
    SELECT 
    eid, 
    in('Involves') as event
    FROM Employee UNWIND event
    ) UNWIND other ) 
GROUP BY eid, other
```

but it seems over-complicated to me. 
Does anybody knows if there is an easier way to express the same query?

Comment: What does mean the parameter nt ?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to replace it. I should have written "eid". I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, your query is correct and this is what you have to do in current version (2.1.x).

From 2.2, with MATCH statement (https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb-docs/blob/master/source/SQL-Match.md), you will be able to write a query very similar to Cypher version:

```
select eid0, eid1, min(start) as firstMet, count(*) from (
    MATCH {class:Person, as:e0}.in("Involves"){as: meeting}.out("Involves"){as:e1}
    return e0.eid as eid0, e1.eid as eid1, meeting.start as start
) group by eid0, eid1
```

This feature is till in beta, probably in final version you will have more operators in the MATCH statement itself and the query will be even shorter

Comment: Grazie mille, Luigi :)